# Why do solc v0.4.17 and v0.4.18 behave differently with the allow-paths primitive?

Tags: solidity, solc

Here's an example contract:

**Nobody.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Nobody {
    function die() public {
        selfdestruct(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

The solc JSON specification to compile the contract is

**Nobody.json**

```
{
    "language": "Solidity",
    "sources": {
        "./Nobody.sol": {
            "urls": [
                "./Nobody.sol"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If the contract is compiled with solc v0.4.17 on an Ubuntu 18.04 system, it errors out.

```
$ cat nobody.json | solc --standard-json --allow-paths .
{"contracts":{},"errors":[{"component":"general","formattedMessage":"Cannot import url (\"./Nobody.sol\"): File outside of allowed directories.","message":"Cannot import url (\"./Nobody.sol\"): File outside of allowed directories.","severity":"error","type":"IOError"}],"sources":{}}
```

But the same contract compiles fine with solc v0.4.18. Why do these solc versions behave differently when it comes to the error `File outside of allowed directories`? What does it mean even? What did change from Solidity version 0.4.17 to 0.4.18?

Comment: Obviously because this issue was fixed between 0.4.17 and 0.4.18 (you can probably even find it on solc github page).

Comment: Checked that already: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases?after=v0.5.0. Couldn't find anything related

Comment: Check their issues page (something like https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues?q=is%3Aissue+%7Ballow-paths%7D+). And you probably wanna check both opened and closed issues.